# How can I iterate through object?

Tags: javascript, object

I've following object

```
Object {  
   14533:Object,
   14598:Object,
   43281:Object,
   275047:Object,
   553883:Object,
   602381:Object,
   602639:Object,
   848489:Object,
   16891417:Object,
   26457880:Object
}
```

where

```
14533 {  
   pageid:14533,
   ns:0,
   title:"India",
   index:1,
   extract:"India, officially the Republic of I…"
}
```

I want to iterate through each of these 10 objects and extract pageid, title, extract

Comment: Above questions iterate through properties of object - I want to iterate through properties of object.
How can I use in this context?  
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

Comment: Then iterate through both?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This question is a replica of [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Do some searching before asking questions or you will be down voted.

**UPDATE:**

As you will find in the link the key ingredient to solve your question is:

```
for(var key in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

The full solution would look something like this:

```
for(var key in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var thisObj = obj[key];
        var thisPageId = thisObj.pageid;
        var thisTitle = thisObj.title;
        var thisExtract = thisObj.extract;

        // console test
        console.log(key, thisPageId, thisTitle, thisExtract);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you think this is a duplicate please flag it and not add as answer.. This will be a _link only answer_ and would end up downvoted and/or deleted

Comment: Both of the above questions are about iterating through object properties and not properties of abject inside object

Comment: @Pravin.Mache I have updated the answer... You said "I want to iterate through each of these 10 objects and extract pageid, title, extract"... The (key in obj) for loop precisely fulfils the first part of your question and the rest is rather straightforward.